# CoreText: Text rendering differently after iOS 9

Tags: ios, core-text

I'm updating an app for iOS 11 that was written in  2011. The app is an interactive book and uses CoreText. When the app is built against iOS 9 the text renders as expected, but when built against iOS 10 or later the text renders incorrectly (see image). The problems seems to be due to a change in the handling of whitespace and/or line spacing. I've tried changing the values for various `CTParagraphStyleSpecifier` but none of them have the desired result. Editing the text is not a viable option so the fix must be related to fixing CoreText. My questions:

1. Is it possible to configure CoreText after iOS 9 to to render like versions upto iOS 9?
2. If it's not possible to fix CoreText, will there be any problems submitting the app pass if it is built against iOS 9?

[image: Screen shot of CoreText rendering on iOS9 and iOS10]

Comment: 1. it is not possible. 2. you should compile it with older xcode, make sure you have arm64 target as well, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't how you make the page layouting, it seems that giving a very spacial CGPathRef to the CTFramesetter, and layout the whole page in one CTFrameRef.

So, if the line spacing (or line height) increases, lines run out of the designed areas.

Adjust following CTParagraphStyleSpecifier maybe helpful, depending on which you were using:

```
kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineHeightMultiple
kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMaximumLineHeight
kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineHeight
kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacing
kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMaximumLineSpacing
kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineSpacing
kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacingAdjustment
```